# Redirect visitors from the non-www version of my website to the www version, without causing a redirect loop that affects the CDN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website hosted on Siteground. Using CNAME, I have redirected the www version of the website to a CloudFront distribution, where oasisdigital.com.ar serves as the origin of the distribution, and [www.oasisdigital.com.ar](http://www.oasisdigital.com.ar) is where the CDN is connected.

However, when I activate the redirection

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Redirect to www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oasisdigital.com.ar [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.oasisdigital.com.ar/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

CloudFront falls into an infinite loop, as it connects to the origin (oasisdigital.com.ar), and htaccess redirects it to [www.oasisdigital.com.ar](http://www.oasisdigital.com.ar).

Is there any way to redirect traffic to the www version, which is the one connected to the CDN, without causing CloudFront to fall into a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CloudFront Functions (viewer-request hook) to implement the redirect instead of at your origin. The advantage is that it will execute at the edge location closes to viewers, so it will be faster than a redirect at your origin. You can set it up in the CloudFront console: here is an example function (untested):

```js
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    if (request.headers.host.value === 'oasisdigital.com.ar') {
        var response = {
            statusCode: 301,
            statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
            headers:
                { 'location': { 'value': 'http://www.oasisdigital.com.ar' } }
            }

        return response;
    }

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Oasisdigital.com.ar is pointing to SiteGround hosting, so CloudFront isn't in use whenever someone visits that version of the website. The code would work on the www version, but there is no point in using it there, as I need to redirect people from the non-www version (origin) to the CloudFront-enabled www version.